# Row count in a dataframe according to a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, data-manipulation

I would like to get the number of entries > 0 for each row of a dataframe, such as to get a new column with this row count.

I performed a loop with which I can obtain row counts, but they are printed as a series of individual vectors. How to get these values in a single column that can then be added as a column in my df?

I have a df with 696 rows and 214 columns.

```
for (i in 2:696) {
   casecount <- length(which(testset[i,13:214] > 0))
   print(casecount)
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

No need in a `for` loop, just do

```
testset$casecount <- rowSums(testset[, 13:214] > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `rowSums` like this:

```
n <- 10

set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n), y=rnorm(n), z=rnorm(n))
dat$count <- rowSums(dat > 0)
dat

              x          y           z count
1   1.262954285  0.7635935 -0.22426789     2
2  -0.326233361 -0.7990092  0.37739565     1
3   1.329799263 -1.1476570  0.13333636     2
4   1.272429321 -0.2894616  0.80418951     2
5   0.414641434 -0.2992151 -0.05710677     1
6  -1.539950042 -0.4115108  0.50360797     1
7  -0.928567035  0.2522234  1.08576936     2
8  -0.294720447 -0.8919211 -0.69095384     0
9  -0.005767173  0.4356833 -1.28459935     1
10  2.404653389 -1.2375384  0.04672617     2
```